# Heads-up Notification Buttons Not Executing

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been searching for a few hours, but could not find any solution to my problem. Does anyone know how to make heads-up notification buttons call a broadcast? My code:

**Alarm Receiver Notification Builder:**

```
       NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarmicon)
                    .setContentTitle("Alarm for " + timeString)
                    .setContentText(MainActivity.alarmLabel.getText().toString())
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // must requires VIBRATE permission
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH); //must give priority to High, Max which will considered as heads-up notification

    //set intents and pending intents to call service on click of "dismiss" action button of notification
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(context, notificationButtonAction.class);
    dismissIntent.setAction(DISMISS_ACTION);
    PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, dismissIntent, 0);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.alarmoff, "Dismiss", piDismiss);

    //set intents and pending intents to call service on click of "snooze" action button of notification
    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, notificationButtonAction.class);
    snoozeIntent.setAction(SNOOZE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent piSnooze = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.snooze, "Snooze", piSnooze);

    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    //to post your notification to the notification bar with a id. If a notification with same id already exists, it will get replaced with updated information.
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

**notificationButtonAction:**

```
public static class notificationButtonAction extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("notificationButtonAction Started");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (SNOOZE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            stopAlarm();
            System.out.println("Alarm Snoozed");
            MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
            ma.setAlarm(true);
        }
        else if (DISMISS_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            stopAlarm();
            System.out.println("Alarm Dismissed");
        }
    }
}
```

My print lines in notificationButtonAction do not print, not even the "notificationButtonAction Started."

I followed the tutorial from Brevity Software (http://www.brevitysoftware.com/blog/how-to-get-heads-up-notifications-in-android/), but their code didn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Tejas, Any luck here?

Comment: Yes, turns out I didn't add the class to the Android Manifest! Whoops!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I didn't add the class to the manifest. My code was fine.